# Not all PHP Sessions saved

Tags: php, session

I am encountering this problem. In my PHP code I am setting two sessions: Cart and Visited.
A cart is clear, visited is a function to view the latest visited products.

My cart has this array:

```
Partnr
Productname
Quantity
Productgroep
Subgroup
```

Visited has this array:

```
Partnr
Productname
Description
Productgroup
Subgroup
```

The session of the cart is stored correctly, but the visited isn't.

This is the code of the cart:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array('quantity' => $_POST['quantity'],
    'partnr' => $_POST['partnr'],
    'hoofdgroep' => $_POST['hoofdgroep'],
    'subgroep' => $_POST['subgroep'],
    'productname' => $_POST['productname']
);
```

And the code of visited:

```
$addition = array('productcode' => $csv[1][1],
    'productname' => $csv[1][2],
    'description' => $csv[1][4],
    'hoofdgroep' => $_GET['hoofdgroep'],
    'subgroep' => $_GET['subgroep']);
$_SESSION['visited'][] = $addition;
```

Does anyone know why my visited won't be saved and by cart is saved?

UPDATE:
Session visited after 3 products shown `$_SESSION['visited']`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [productcode] => AD-HPR-150-CR50
            [productname] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Adapterring voor HPR-150
                )

            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Adaptar
                )

            [hoofdgroep] => lighting
            [subgroep] => accessoires
        )

)
```

My cart session with three products in it `$_SESSION['cart']`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [partnr] => AD-HPR-150-CR50
            [hoofdgroep] => lighting
            [subgroep] => accessoires
            [productname] => Adapterring voor HPR-150
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [partnr] => AD-HPR-150-CR50
            [hoofdgroep] => lighting
            [subgroep] => accessoires
            [productname] => Adapterring voor HPR-150
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [partnr] => HP-CDT1006B-24
            [hoofdgroep] => lighting
            [subgroep] => diffuselite-dome
            [productname] => HighPower 45inch Compact Diffused Tube Light (with inline dimmer 10 turn locking knob) Blue, 24VDC
        )

)
```

UPDATE 2:
And the revised code of visited:

```
$addition = array('productcode' => $csv[1][1],
    'productname' => (string)$csv[1][2],
    'description' => (string)$csv[1][4],
    'hoofdgroep' => $_GET['hoofdgroep'],
    'subgroep' => $_GET['subgroep']);
$_SESSION['visited'][] = $addition;
```

Comment: Are both these code snippets on the same page? If not, did you do a session_start() properly on all pages?

Comment: have you turned on error reporting, you  can put ini_set('display_errors', 1); after the opening <?php tag.

Comment: @RaoufAthar yes, these are on the same page. The first line of the document says: session_start();

Comment: if you print_r($_SESSION['visited']); what is the output if any?

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @RaoufAthar Only the last item I tried to put in there, but no other ones.


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [productcode] => AD-HPR-150-CR50
            [productname] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Adapterring voor HPR-150
                )

            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Adaptar
                )

            [hoofdgroep] => lighting
            [subgroep] => accessoires
        )

)

Comment: what does `print_r($csv)` show? and for sure, pleas provide the output of the `print_r` of both session variable. both as UPDATE in your Quesion post, not in the comments ;)

Comment: Are you sure your code says $_SESSION['visited'][] with those extra []? And does any other place in your file look like $_SESSION['visited'] = something?

Comment: @RaoufAthar Yes with the extra []. I don't have another $_SESSION['visited'] = something. In one place I check if there is something in it (with ==) and I write the session to a new variable (named $csv).

Comment: @helle I edited my original post ;-)

Comment: you forgott to provide the `$csv` value

Comment: Just curious, is it possible to POST values and have GET values on the same page at the same time?...

Comment: There was a comment of Vasil just a few seconds ago about the SimpleXMLElement Object. When I cast these into a string, it works!

Comment: @War10ck ofcourse. `<form action="index.php?getVar1=1&getVar2=2" method="POST">`

Comment: @RobinV91NL is your question answered now or do you still have some troubles?

Comment: It has all been answered. Thanks!